# Opt for, to be up for (and to be down for)

Tags: phrases, idioms, slang

What's the difference between **I opt for** the party and I'm up for the party? And, to make it more complex, I'm down for the party.

But I'm especially interested in the first two.

Comment: "To be *opt* for something" is ungrammatical.  The rest of the question is a duplicate of this one: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17852/what-does-the-phrase-i-m-down-with-mean

Comment: Actually after having looked at that question above, it doesn't really do a very good job of answering your particular question here.

Answer (score 1):

> "*I'm opt for the party*" is ungrammatical.

"*up for*" and "*down for*" with respect to parties and activities in general mean the same thing: *I want to go do it*.

The phrase ["To be up for something"](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/feel-up-to) means

> to feel that you are strong or healthy enough to do something

The phrase "To be down for something" is more of a slang term and I always picture it as like when you've put your name *down* on the list indicating you want to participate then you are *down* for it.

Note that being "down *with*" something is a little different and means more like you are in agreement with the sentiment or idea being expressed.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "I opt for". I opt for the party and I'm down for the party - are these the same?

Comment: To *opt for* the party means to **choose** the party (over something else).  Think of choosing one **option** among two or more.  (And @Jim already answered wrt *up for* and *down for*.)

Answer (score 1):

Opting for something is choosing for something. In the context of a party, it sounds unnatural: "I choose for the party".

To be up for something means you are interested for the party, as in "You are already standing up to get on your way to the party".

"Down for" is, I think, bad. I think it should be "down with". Maybe referring to "downtown" (just a guess) ?